# Using append is automatically converting strings to integers

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one of the columns is strings:

```
> head(a$type)
[1] Sell Sell Sell Buy  Buy  Buy 
Levels: Buy Sell
```

When I `append` to it, it converts everything to an int:

```
> head(append(a$type, "Buy"))
[1] "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1"
```

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You actually have a factor, not a string.

Comment: ...and even then, nothing has (technically) been converted to an int. The factor was _already_ integer codes, and what you've gotten back are those integers converted to characters.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3443576/946850

Answer (score 3):

Your `a$type` variable is actually a factor.  To convert a factor to a character, use

```
a$type = as.character(a$type)
```

And then your append command should work.