# R: Web scraping JSON, extracting information from nest

Tags: json, r, web-scraping, jsonlite

I am trying to use tidyJSON to extract information from JSON, but I am open to any R package that can achieve my ends. I took a look at the documentation and vignittes and found the [complex example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html) was helpful. However,  the information I want is nested inside of a non-key-value pair and I am not sure how to access it. I am interested in getting `appid`, `name`, `developer`, etc., but this information is within `570` and `730`:

```
{"570":{"appid":570,"name":"Dota 2","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":71,"owners":102151578,"owners_variance":259003,"players_forever":102151578,"players_forever_variance":259003,"players_2weeks":9436299,"players_2weeks_variance":89979,"average_forever":11727,"average_2weeks":1229,"median_forever":277,"median_2weeks":662,"ccu":811259,"price":"0","tags":{"Free to Play":22678,"MOBA":7808,"Strategy":7415,"Multiplayer":6757,"Team-Based":4848,"Action":4602,"e-sports":4089,"Online Co-Op":3669,"Competitive":3553,"PvP":2655,"RTS":2267,"Difficult":2129,"RPG":2114,"Fantasy":2044,"Tower Defense":2024,"Co-op":1898,"Character Customization":1514,"Replay Value":1487,"Action RPG":1397,"Simulation":1024}},

"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","developer":"Valve","publisher":"Valve","score_rank":78,"owners":29225079,"owners_variance":154335,"players_forever":28552354,"players_forever_variance":152685,"players_2weeks":9102348,"players_2weeks_variance":88410,"average_forever":17648,"average_2weeks":791,"median_forever":5030,"median_2weeks":358,"ccu":543626,"price":"1499","tags":{"FPS":17082,"Multiplayer":13744,"Shooter":12833,"Action":10881,"Team-Based":10369,"Competitive":9664,"Tactical":8529,"First-Person":7329,"e-sports":6716,"PvP":6383,"Online Co-Op":5714,"Military":4621,"Co-op":4435,"Strategy":4424,"War":4361,"Realistic":3196,"Trading":3191,"Difficult":3158,"Fast-Paced":3100,"Moddable":2496}}
```

There are many thousands of such entries. Is there a way to skip the "top-level" and look within the nest?
The JSON information is from http://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks

Comment: You can try `listviewer::jsonedit` to help you visualize the data first. The maybe [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) couçd help you extract what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```
library(jsonlite)
data = fromJSON("http://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks")

appid = lapply(data, function(x){x$appid})
name = lapply(data, function(x){x$name})

df = data.frame(appid = unlist(appid),
                name = unlist(name),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Result:

```
> head(df)
        appid                             name
570       570                           Dota 2
730       730 Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
578080 578080    PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS
440       440                  Team Fortress 2
271590 271590               Grand Theft Auto V
433850 433850           H1Z1: King of the Kill
```

I'll let you add the rest of the information

**Edit: Adding arrays to a dataframe**

Adding the tags information for each game in the data frame is possible. And the times tagged as well. For each game you must store an array of tag names in a column and the tag quantities in another.

After the definition of `df` add the following lines:

```
for(k in 1:nrow(d)){
    d$tags[k] = list(names(data[[k]]$tags))
    d$tagsQ[k] = list(unlist(data[[k]]$tags))
}
```

This will give you:

```
> d["570",]
    appid   name
570   570 Dota 2

tags
570 Free to Play, MOBA, Strategy, Multiplayer, Team-Based, Action, e-sports, Online Co-Op, Competitive, PvP, RTS, Difficult, RPG, Fantasy, Tower Defense, Co-op, Character Customization, Replay Value, Action RPG, Simulation

tagsQ
570 22686, 7810, 7420, 6759, 4850, 4603, 4092, 3672, 3555, 2657, 2267, 2130, 2116, 2045, 2024, 1898, 1514, 1487, 1397, 1023
```

In this situation, columns `tags` and `tagsQ` contain lists. To obtain the second tag and quantity for `appid 570` do:

```
> df["570","tags"][[1]][2]
[1] "MOBA"

> d["570","tagsQ"][[1]][2]
MOBA 
7810
```

Comment: thanks. I am also struggling with converting "tags" field into a data structure that can be put into the data frame. I end up with a named list that can't be inserted into the data frame. Is there an easy way to convert the tags to dummy boolean columns in the data frame, or to concatenate it into a comma-separated value in a field of the data frame? I am really bad with list structures.

Comment: I tried: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list/named-list-members, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059798/list-of-named-lists-to-data-frame and Google