# Convert strings in dataset to unique numeric values in R

Tags: r, statistics, dataset

so I have a dataset with soccer teams in the variable `d`, where I omitted the NA (missing values)

```
d <- na.omit(bundesliga3)
```

But when I try to get the unique teams for both the home team and away team, it does not work. I've tried the same exact code with a different dataset and it works.

```
teams <- unique(c(d$HomeTeam, d$AwayTeam))
```

I need this because I want to create a data list of unique numeric values for all the teams, and obviously the same team should have the same number whether it's home or away. What am I doing wrong?

```
data_list <- list(HomeGoals = d$HomeGoals, AwayGoals = d$AwayGoals, 
              HomeTeam = as.numeric(factor(d$HomeTeam, levels=teams)),
              AwayTeam = as.numeric(factor(d$AwayTeam, levels=teams)),
              Season = as.numeric(factor(d$Season, levels=seasons)),
              n_teams = length(teams), n_games = nrow(d), 
              n_seasons = length(seasons))
```

EDIT: Here is output of data from `str(d)`

```
 'data.frame':  1480 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Season     : Factor w/ 5 levels "2011/12","2012/13",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Week       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ HomeTeam   : Factor w/ 25 levels "Augsburg","Bayern Munich",..: 5 1 7 12 13 23 24 2 19 9 ...
 $ AwayTeam   : Factor w/ 25 levels "Augsburg","Bayern Munich",..: 11 9 25 14 20 22 16 18 17 19 ...
 $ HomeGoals  : int  3 2 0 2 0 3 2 0 2 1 ...
 $ AwayGoals  : int  1 2 3 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ MatchResult: num  1 0 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:50] 1481 1482 1483 1484 1485 1486 1487 1488 1489 1490 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:50] "1481" "1482" "1483" "1484" ...
```

EDIT2: Here's as much of the output of `dput(d)` as I could add

```
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), .Label = c("2011/12", "2012/13", "2013/14", "2014/15", "2015/16"
), class = "factor"), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L), HomeTeam = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 23L, 24L, 2L, 19L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 20L,
```

Comment: Without any data to work with it is hard to provide a good answer. Can you post sample of your data? Also, output of `str(d)` would help.

Comment: I've added the output of the variable "d"

Comment: Can you add output of `dput(d)` and `str(d)` in R from that data frame `d`? Images are not possible to be read and interpreted.

Comment: How can I add that here? Thanks

Comment: Edit question , copy / paste output from those commands and use {} to format as code.

Comment: I can't add output of `dput(d)`because of the character limit

Comment: I assume that you [lose the "factor" attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443576/how-to-concatenate-factors) when concatenatenating the two columns. Try to concatenate their "levels"; `unique(c(levels(away), levels(home)))`

Comment: @alexis_laz that seems to have done the trick, thanks! but I don't understand why, exactly?

Comment: @MJ95 "factor"s are "integer" vectors with "attributes" (`?factor`; `unclass(factor(letters[1:3]))`) and a `print` method that _prints_ a "factor" as if it were a "character". Also, `?c` removes "attributes" and so, just two "integer"s are concatenated in situations like `c(factor(letters[1:4]), factor(letters[3:6]))`.